# iPhone Network Share Access

Tags: iphone, file, networking

I am trying to download a data file from a local network share to an iPhone device.  I have placed the file on a computer on the network and can view through browsers such as Chrome or Mozilla, from any computer on the local network.

However, Safari on a Mac and the iPhone do not find the file!  An example of the URL I use is 'file://computer/SharedDocs/file.csv'.

Why do Safari and the iPhone fail to find the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iPhone does not support mapping of shared drives as needed to access a remote file through the file: URL-scheme.

Try to make the file available through one of the supported url-schemes, eg. http: